# Is it possible to have a hyperlink open in a new tab that is inside a pdf that is inside of a frame in classic asp?

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, frame

I Have a classic asp site i am working on. The page has two frames one directly below the other. A Customer has to be able to view a pdf to continue onto the next page. To get to the next page they have to click on a hyper link inside of the pdf that is being viewed. If they cannot see the pdf then they have to download adobe reader which i have included a link to in the top frame.(The top frame has some text and the link) now the bottom frame(contains the pdf) this works fine except when i click the link that is in the pdf the page then opens in that same bottom frame that contained the pdf. It needs to be target _blank. Or whatever you would call it to basically either over ride the two frames and just open in the browser or open in a new tab or window which i cant get either to do. This problem is in IE and Firefox but in chrome it over rides the two frames and opens correctly. Is there any way to get this to occur in IE and Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

I've found this resource about your issue:
http://forums.adobe.com/thread/853394

They say there's no target attribute to set. But they think (and i also think) that if you place a :

```
javascript:window.open('http://yoururl.com');
```

it should work, always if you can accept the security alert message (Abobe PDF is trying to execute a script... blah blah)

If your continue reading carefully it seems they solved the problem using Adobe scripting inside inDesign

Hope this helps...